# ControllerView transition changed after updating latest Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I am not sure if anyone else is having the same problem but after updating Xcode to the latest version

all my ControllerViews are showing in "Stacked Card" like transition view (not sure what its called)

[image]

[image]

the question here is how can I revert back and make it to a full view and what is this current view called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior has been changed.

Set the modalPresentationStyle as full screen.

```
viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

Comment: Thank you! I just also found that it can be changed from the storyboard "Presentation" option